# Glassfish create JDBCResources, -Pools and Security Realms from application

Tags: glassfish, administration

How can I create JDBCResources, -Pools and Security Realms in a Glassfish 3.1 Server from within my Application, if they are not already created? I am writing an application that relies on this resources, however I don't want to configure the server manually every time the application is deployed on a different server.

Doing this with a shell script feels like a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glassfish provides a REST interface. You can create a new security (authentication) realm in a certain configuration (say, `server-config` in a DAS on localhost, admin port 4848) with a POST to:

http://localhost:4848/management/domain/configs/config/server-config/security-service/auth-realm

Do a GET to that resource to see the parameters.

You can use the same interface to create connection pools.

Comment: Thx, I already tried to read the values as XML and JSON documents and it works great.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found a solution for half of the Question.

I created a file called `glassfish-resources.xml` in my WEB-INF folder and added the following content to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool
            name="java:app/jdbc/BeerUserPool"
            res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            datasource-classname="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
            pool-resize-quantity="2"
            max-pool-size="32"
            steady-pool-size="0"
            statement-timeout-in-seconds="30">
        <property name="User" value="USERNAME"></property>
        <property name="Password" value="PASSWORD"></property>
        <property name="PortNumber" value="12345678"></property>
        <property name="dataBaseName" value="DATABASE_NAME"></property>
        <property name="ServerName" value="yourDBUrl.com"></property>
        <property name="Ssl" value="false"></property>
        <property name="ProtocolVersion" value="0"></property>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource 
        pool-name="java:app/jdbc/BeerUserPool"
        jndi-name="java:app/jdbc/BeerUser"></jdbc-resource>
    <
</resources>
```

Addingt the java:app/ to the names is important, without it it won't work correctly. This connection pool is also only application scoped and gets destroyed after the application is undebloyed (except you add an additional argument).

This pool can now be accessed with JPA with the following `persistence.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="jsf-jpa-war" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:app/jdbc/BeerUser</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

However I found no soultion how I can define the security realms in the same way.

Comment: I'm at same point as you: I defined the resource and the resource-pool but I don't see a way to specify the realm...

Comment: Finally, did you find a way to create the realm in GlassFish from the application? 
To create the data source you can also use the annotation @DataSourceDefinition or a <data-source> tag in web.xml, which is more portable.